# Election privileges missing from privileges page

Tags: feature-request, election, privileges

Previously, there had been an entry in the [privileges list page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) for "Nominate moderators".

While that entry was [outdated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75399/is-the-nominate-moderators-privilege-mislabeled-in-the-privilege-list/75400#75400), it is no longer present, and has not been updated or replaced with another entry in the latest changes to the privileges list.

Should there be entries in the privilege list for "Vote in moderator elections" and "Self-nominate for moderator elections", or is this covered elsewhere, on another page?

Answer (score 9):

I think this issue should be bubbled back up to the front page, especially now that badges are involved with elections.  A member needs 150 reputations in order to participate.

[image]

Comment: This makes some sense, but the Just In Time info about elections seems more ideal. Seeing you've earned a privilege you can use once a year seems unhelpful when the one-a-year event also shows you the requirements. It would be very easy to forget this privilege, it almost seems like noise since it's not always (usually) an actionable priviledge

Comment: @BenBrocka: That assumes that moderator elections are only once a year.

Comment: @NicolBolas they are extremely rare, except the case of SO I do believe they are only once a year (and were on SO until demand has proven it necessary). In reality it's often rarer than a year on non-SO sites, many betas go over a year with no election whatsoever. The point is it's extremely rare, not an every day or even every month task.

Answer (score 6):

There should definitely be an entry for voting in the primary and election phases as that's fixed at 150 rep.

It's potentially harder to include an entry for nomination as the threshold can change during an election.

At the outset and until there are 30 nominees the threshold is fixed (3,000 on Stack Overflow, 300 on other sites), but as soon as there are 30 nominees the next person who wants to nominate needs *more* rep than the user with the lowest rep who's already nominated. If the lowest rep user has 4,000 rep (using SO as an example), then the nominating user needs 4,001 rep or more.

The privilege should be included at the minimum value but with the above explanation (or a better worded version of it!) included on the page itself.