# Who can vote on moderator elections?

Tags: support, election

When a moderator election is held on a graduated Stack Exchange site, which users get to vote for moderator candidates?

I tried to look at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election/4 and https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/election but the threads there didn't seem to list this information.  The information wasn't easy to find on Meta SE either.  So I'm asking this question hoping that it will make this pieces of information easier to find.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have at least 150 reputation on the site to be allowed to vote.  This information can be found in the answer [Election privileges missing from privileges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274513/222298).